# Running valgrind in virtual machine

Tags: valgrind

How much valid are the valgrind logs showing invalid accesses and data races,when running it in virtual machine and not in a native linux system. The reason being,in a virtual machine,everything is virtual.

Comment: What is your software doing exactly ?

Answer (score 2):

Unless you are writing some kernel specific stuff I would say that they are all valid. Maybe just your virtual machine has different timings than real machine?